# Expectation of uniform random variable with indicator function

Tags: probability

Sorry for the stupid question, but why is $\mathbb{E}[X*\mathbb{I}_{X<c}] = c^{2}/2$,
where X is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, c is some constant and $\mathbb{I}$ is the indicator function?

Comment: Did you try writing out the expectation as an integral in terms of uniform density and the expression inside the expectation?

Comment: Sorry, it is obvious to me now.

Comment: @user0347284 depending upon the value of $c$ the answer could change. $\frac{c^2}{2}$ is only valid till $c \in (0,1)$ otherwise if $c\geq1$ then it should be $\frac{1}{2}$ while if $c\leq 0$ it should be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E[X \mathbb{I}_{X < c}] = \int_0^1 x \cdot \mathbb{I}_{x<c} \, dx = \int_0^c x \, dx = \cdots$$